# Store data during for and while loops

Tags: matlab, for-loop, while-loop, save

I need some help to store values in MATLAB using the following code:

```
for n = 1:some number
    iter = 0;
    while % condition
        iter = iter + 1 ;
        for k = 1:9
            % call the integrator 9 times
            [t,s] = ode113(@(t,y) eqns, [0 t{k}], X{k}, options);
            % X{k} contains 9 initial conditions where each has 6 values
            x{k} = s(:,1:6)
            % x{k} = stores each arc from integration
            x = 1x9 cell array where each cell is #rowsx6
        end
    end
    state(n,:) = x;
end
```

The issue I am having is that `state` does not have all `n` values of `x`. For example, if `n = 2`, state is size 2x9 BUT only the `x` values for `n = 2` is stored; nothing is saved for `n = 1`. I also tried: `state{n}(iter,:)` inside the `while` loop and it also only stores the `x` data from the last iteration. It appears that the variable state is being overwritten. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your `while` loop condition seems to be the reason of that. Please create a [mre]; without which we can only guess.

Comment: Hi Sardar, I suspect it is the while loop but I have not been able to see why. I modified the question.

Comment: How do you initialize `state`? Is it a cell array? I guess it must be, otherwise  that assignment would be illegal. A [mre] is code that we can copy-paste and run ourselves. That ensures that all variables are defined and all statements make sense, which is necessary for us to really understand what you are doing. It is hard to guess why an assignment doesn't do as you expect it to, if we don't have complete code. Please read the page linked above, it'll help you get useful answers.

Comment: Hi Cris, state is initialized using []; making a minimal example would be pretty difficult due to the fact that there so many dependencies that it would be hard to simplify. I edited the code to simplify as much I as could.

Answer (score 0):

got it! thanks for inputs. variable was not assigned properly.